# Use DB to generate airflow tasks dynamically

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I want to run an airflow dag like so ->

- I have 2 airflow workers W1 and W2.
- In W1 I have scheduled a single task (W1-1) but in W2, I want to create X number of tasks (W2-1, W2-2 ... W2-X).
- The number X and the bash command for each task  will be derived from a DB call.
- All tasks for worker W2 should run in parallel after W1 completes.

This is my code

```
dag = DAG('deploy_single', catchup=False, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='16 15 * * *')

t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='dummy_task',
        bash_command='echo hi > /tmp/hi',
        queue='W1_queue',
        dag=dag)

get_all_engines = "select full_command, queue_name from internal_airflow_hosts where logical_group = 'live_engines';"

db_creds = json.loads(open('/opt/airflow/db_creds.json').read())
conn_dict = db_creds["airflowdb_local"]
connection = psycopg2.connect(**conn_dict)

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(get_all_engines)
records = cursor.fetchall()
i = 1
for record in records:
    t = BashOperator(
        task_id='script_test_'+str(i),
        bash_command="{full_command} ".format(full_command=str(record[0])),
        queue=str(record[1]),
        dag=dag)
    t.set_upstream(t1)
    i += 1

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

However, when I run this, the task on W1 completed successfully but all tasks on W2 failed. In the airflow UI, I can see that it can resolve the correct number of tasks (10 in this case) but each of these 10 failed.

Looking at the logs, I saw that on W2 (which is on a different machine), airflow could not find the `db_creds.json` file.

I do not want to provide the DB creds file to W2.

My question is how can an airflow task be created dynamically in this case?
Basically i want to run a DB query on the airflow server and assign tasks to one or more workers based on the results of that query. The DB will contain updated info about which engines are active etc I want the DAG to reflect this. From logs, it looks like each worker runs the DB query. Providing access to DB to each worker is not an option.

Comment: The reason your W2 tasks failed is the task being run must be present in the DAG.  When it's hardcoded it isn't an issue, but since you are dynamically creating your tasks, the workers/scheduler/webserver all need access to whatever dependencies are required to build the DAG.  In your case that is a db connection.  @Viraj Parekh's suggestion allows you to shift that dependency to an airflow variable, which the worker will have access to.

Comment: @cwurtz - update added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to store the information in an [Airflow Variable](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html).

You can fetch the information needed to dynamically generate the DAG (and necessary configs) in a Variable and have W2 access it from there.

Variables are an [airflow model](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py#L4388) that can be used to store static information (information that does not have an associated timestamp) that all tasks can access.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try using airflow variable and update.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you @viraj-parekh and @cwurtz.

After much trial and error, found the correct way to use airflow variables for this case.

Step 1) We create another script called `gen_var.py`and place it in the dag folder. This way, the scheduler will pick up and generate the variables. If the code for generating variables is within the `deploy_single` dag then we run into the same dependency issue as the worker will try and process the dag too.

```
"""
Code that goes along with the Airflow tutorial located at:
https://github.com/airbnb/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py
"""
import json
import psycopg2
from airflow.models import Variable
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

get_all_engines = "select full_command, queue_name from internal_airflow_hosts where logical_group = 'live_engines';"

db_creds = json.loads(open('/opt/airflow/db_creds.json').read())
conn_dict = db_creds["airflowdb_local"]
connection = psycopg2.connect(**conn_dict)

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(get_all_engines)
records = cursor.fetchall()

hosts = {}
i = 1
for record in records:
    comm_dict = {}
    comm_dict['full_command'] = str(record[0])
    comm_dict['queue_name'] = str(record[1])
    hosts[i] = comm_dict
    i += 1

cursor.close()
connection.close()

Variable.set("hosts",hosts,serialize_json=True)
```

Note the call to `serialize_json`. Airflow will try to store the variable as a string. If you want it to be stored as a dict, then use `serialize_json=True`. Airflow will still store it as string via `json.dumps`

Step 2) Simplify the dag and call this `"hosts"` variable (now deserialize to get back the dict) like so -

```
hoztz = Variable.get("hosts",deserialize_json=True)
for key in hoztz:
    host = hoztz.get(key)
    t = BashOperator(
        task_id='script_test_'+str(key),
        bash_command="{full_command} ".format(full_command=str(host.get('full_command'))),
        queue=str(host.get('queue_name')),
        dag=dag)
    t.set_upstream(t1)
```

Hope it helps someone else.